# View example.com/tags/xyz works, now how to get example.com/tags working?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

Using Drupal 7.31 with Views 7.x-3.8.

I cloned the existing default "Taxonomy term" View and enabled it. Now if I visit `www.example.com/tags/xyz` I get a nice listing of all nodes tagged with `xyz` (I have Pathauto enabled).  And same for `www.example.com/tags/abc`.

However if I visit `www.example.com/tags` it displays "Page not found".  So my question is how can I get `www.example.com/tags` to list all the terms for the `tags` taxonomy?  Do I have to create a new view or can the one view handle it all?

Comment: You should be able to set that in the options for the contextual filter

Comment: @Clive: If you're talking about tweaking the "When the filter value is NOT in the URL" settings, I couldn't get this to work.  If you can tell me specifically or point to article/documentation that'd be great

Comment: when the filter value is NOT in the URL - set this to show all if you want it show everything by default. if that doesn't work - try uploading a screenshot of the view page, and then the contextual filter dialog so we can see what you see